# Malformed URL when connecting applet to servlet

Tags: java, postgresql, servlets, applet

I'm trying to access a servlet from a java applet and set the servlet's response in the applet's text field.
I'm using tomcat 7.0 and my jre/jdk are fully updated.
The servlet runs fine (correct output in the browser) when invoked from the browser as localhost:8080/hello/hello?query=select * from airports

(where airports is the name of the database)

However when i run the applet in appletviewer, i get a Malformed URL exception thrown..

Code for Applet:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

/*
<applet code="lab101" width=500 height=270>
</applet>
*/

public class lab101 extends Applet implements ActionListener{

TextArea t;

Panel p,q,r;
CheckboxGroup c;
Checkbox ins,dis,del,update;     //Checkboxes are included just for testing purposes.
TextField f;
Label l1;
Button b;

public void init(){

setLayout(new FlowLayout());

b=new Button("Run");
l1=new Label("Query:");
c=new CheckboxGroup();
t=new TextArea("",10,50);
p=new Panel();
q=new Panel();
r=new Panel();


p.add(t);

ins=new Checkbox("Insert",c,false);

dis=new Checkbox("Display",c,true);

del=new Checkbox("Delete",c,false);

update=new Checkbox("Update",c,false);

f=new TextField(50);

q.add(ins);
q.add(dis);
q.add(del);
q.add(update);

r.add(l1);
r.add(f);
r.add(b);

b.addActionListener(this);

add(p);
add(q);
add(r);

try{
URL url=new URL("127.0.0.1:8080/hello/hello?query=select * from airports");


URLConnection servletconnection=url.openConnection();

servletconnection.setDoInput(true);

InputStream in=servletconnection.getInputStream();
String s="";
int ch;
loop:while(1>0){
ch=in.read();
if(ch==-1) break loop;
else s+=(char)ch;
}

t.setText(s);


}//try close

catch(MalformedURLException e){
t.setText("Malformed URL Exception occured.");}

catch(IOException e){
  t.setText("IO exception occured");}


}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
}


public void start(){
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
}

}//class ends
```

Code for servlet:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class hello extends HttpServlet{

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();

String query=request.getParameter("query");

Connection link=null;
Statement statement=null;
ResultSet results=null;

try{

Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test";
link=DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","hooligan");
out.println("Successful connection");
}

catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
out.println("Unable to load driver");
}

catch(SQLException e){
out.println("Cannot connect to database");
}


try{
statement=link.createStatement();
//String select="select * from airports";
results=statement.executeQuery(query);
}

catch(SQLException e){
out.println("Cannot execute query");
e.printStackTrace();
}


try{

out.println();

while(results.next()){

out.println("Name: " + results.getString(1));
out.println("Location: " + results.getString(2));
//System.out.println("Account no: " + results.getInt(3));

System.out.println();}

}

catch(SQLException e){
out.println("Error retrieving data");
}


try{
link.close();}

catch(SQLException e){
out.println("Unable to disconnect");}


out.close();
out.flush();
}}
```

Any thoughts?

P.S. i also noticed that if i use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 i get a Security Exception thrown (Probably because the applet is unsigned?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 (actually 3) problems:

First, an applet is only allowed to fire HTTP requests on the exact URL base as where the applet is been served from. You can obtain it by [`Applet#getCodeBase()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) which needs to be used as follows:

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "hello?query=select * from airports");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
// ...
```

Second, your query string contains illegal characters for use in URLs (space, asterisk). You need to use [`URLEncoder#encode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to URL-encode the query string.

```
String query = URLEncoder.encode("select * from airports", "UTF-8");
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase(), "hello?query=" + query);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
// ...
```

You also need to ensure that you open the HTML/JSP page with the applet in the browser on the same base URL as where the servlet runs. E.g. http://localhost:8080/hello/pagewithapplet.html and thus not from commandline or by an appletviewer or something. The applet *really* needs to be served from the same webserver as where the servlet runs.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem as stated in the question, your third problem is that sending a plain SQL statement as request parameter is a *very* bad idea. What if a hacker decompiles your applet and figures how the applet-servlet communication is done and then modifies the SQL statement into something else, such as `delete from airports`?

Do not do the SQL in the applet, do it in the servlet only and let the applet send specific commands only, such as `hello?query=list_airports` (which is actually still open for further optimization, think of a REST webservice, but that's left up to you as an exercise).

Comment: Thanks for the reply BalusC, but i'm still facing a problem with applet-servlet communication. The point is that the applet's codebase is C:\program files\java\jdk1.6.0_16\bin and the servlet resides in the webapps of tomcat directory, c:\tomcat\webapps\hello\WEB-INF\classes\hello.class

I changed the url so as the include the usage of URLEncoder. I put the html file and compiled class file of the applet in the hello directory (c:\tomcat\webapps\hello) with the URL as 

url=new URL(getCodeBase(), "hello?query=" +query);

i get an IO exception in my code when i run it via the html file.

Comment: The part of code that can cause an IOException in the applet is probably:
`code`
InputStream in=servletconnection.getInputStream();
String s="";
int ch;
loop:while(1>0){
ch=in.read();
if(ch==-1) break loop;
else s+=(char)ch;
}

t.setText(s);
`code`


The servlet's response is returned as out.println(queryresult); which needs to be read via the InputStream in the applet.

When i commented the code involving IO, and ran the applet, the connection to the servlet was successful.

Comment: You need to run the applet in a webpage which you open by a webbrowser. The webpage must be served by the server where the servlet runs. You shouldn't run the applet individually from commandline or applettester or something.

Comment: Yes,i ran the applet via a webbrowser using the applet tag in its html. To get information about exceptions, while catching exceptions, i had set messages that inform me about the occured exception

`code`
catch(IOException e){
  t.setText("IO exception occured");}
`code`

How can i set the webpage to be run by the server(tomcat)?

As i'm using CodeBase and then concatenating the query, i'm not able to use 127.0.0.1, instead the URL returned by codebase ie. C:\tomcat\webapps\hello is concatenated wit the query and passed on to the servlet. I cannot see a role of the server in this. Please help

Comment: You're still running the HTML file from local disk file system. You should not open the HTML in browser by `file:///c:/path/to/file.html` or something (do not doubleclick it in windows explorer). You should open the HTML by `http://localhost:8080/hello/file.html`. You need to put the HTML file and applet code in the same Tomcat webapp as where the servlet runs.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks Balus C, i got that working!

Unfortuantely, i still have a problem. This is the 4th applet loaded from the start of my project in the browser.  All applets have their class files embedded in the applet tag of their respective html files. I was loading one applet after another by using AppletContext. The 3rd applet, which is supposed to load this one via a button needs to open the url http:localhost:8080/hello/file.html

How can i link a button of another applet to this address?

thanks a lot for your replies, really glad after getting this to work.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a fundamentally different problem/question. Please don't use comments for this. Just press `Ask Question` button on the right top.

Comment: Got it. Placed all my project files in the same webapps folder, and linked it via Applet Context. Thanks a lot Balus C!

Answer (score 0):

`URL url=new URL("127.0.0.1:8080/hello/hello?query=select * from airports")`

is not a valid URL.